# Using jQuery.event to detect the link that was clicked

Tags: jquery, events

I am trying the following:

```
var showTooltip = function(event) {
if(event.target == "<a href=\"view_repair.php\">") {
$tooltip
  .text('View full repair details')
  .fadeIn('slow');
positionTooltip(event);
```

console.log(event.target) in Firebug gives

```
<a href="view_repair.php">
```

But the code inside the if statement isn't being run. Is this because the if statement is comparing against the actual string it's being given - including the escapes?

When I change the *if* statement to:

```
if(event.target == event.target)
```

I get the desired result.

What I'd really like to be able to do is use the link name/title to do the comparison, i.e. (pseudo code):

```
if(event.target.text() == "View")
```

Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to compare a DOM element object with a string representation of what it's tag might look like, which aren't equal. How about something like:

```
if(event.target.attr('href') == 'view_repair.php')
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
alert('event target is:' + event.target);
```

This should tell you the value.

You can test your value for comparison with

```
alert('<a href=\"view_repair.php\">');
```

Comment: missing quote in first statement

Comment: @TStamper There's no missing quote ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Why not give the link a title attribute and extract the tooltip text from it, then remove it.  Then you don't have to hardcode any values in your function.

```
 <a href="view_repair.php" title="View full repair details" class="tool">View</a>


 $('.tool').each( function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     var tip = $this.attr('title');
     $this.removeAttr('title');
     $this.hover(
            function(e) {
                $tooltip.text(tip).fadeIn('slow');
                positionTooltip(e);
            },
            function(e) {
                $tooltip.fadeOut('slow');
            }
     );
});
```